# PHP strtotime issue, causing error

Tags: php, strtotime

```
if(!empty($maintenance_options['disable'])) {
    $currentDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . date("H:i:s")));
    $nodate = $maintenance_options['disable'], strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . date("H:i:s"));

    if($currentDate > $nodate) {
        echo 'if';
    } else {
        echo 'else';
    }
}
```

I have this weird error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on line 53

Line 53 is

```
$nodate = $maintenance_options['disable'], strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . date("H:i:s"));
```

but that line seems to be fine? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is that line intended to be a function call? You have an extra closing parenthesis before the semicolon.

Comment: What is date("Y-m-d") . date("H:i:s") supposed to be?  If you just want the current time, use time() instead of strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . date("H:i:s"))

Comment: @EduardoGalván what "closing parenthesis"? they all match

Comment: What is the comma after `maintenance_options['disable']` for?

Comment: I'm not sure how much clearer the error message can be - you can't have a comma there in PHP.

Comment: @iainn so how could I change the code but still have the same PHP results?

Comment: @J.Doe What do you want `$nodate` to actually contain? It's hard to know how to fix the problem when all you've posted is invalid code.

Comment: @iainn I want `$nodate` to output `$maintenance_options['disable']` as `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Comment: @heybignick A tut said I had to do it like that

Comment: @PietervandenHam A tut said I had to do it like that

Comment: What is an example value for $maintenance_options['disable']?

Comment: @heybignick It's `2016-07-04 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was a bit hard to understand, but I think I know what's being asked.  It appears that $currentDate needs to be the current PHP time and $nodate needs to be set to the time value of $maintenance_options['disable'].  If this is true, the following code should work.

```
$currentDate = time();
$nodate = strtotime($maintenance_options['disable']);
```

Comment: that works, thank you. I was thinking too difficult